# JPA query returns BigInteger instead of Long

Tags: java, jpa

I have a repository class which is expected to return a List as below. It is executing fine but, when I try to check whether another Long value present inside the result list, I observed that, the result list is actually not Long type, but BigInteger. Why it is happening? How can I force the repository method to return Long, instead of BigInteger?

*Repository Class*

```
     @Repository
     public interface CarsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cars, Long> {
         @Query(value = "select Id from Cars WHERE Colour = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
         public List<Long> fetchCarsWithColour(String colour);
     }
```

*Entity class*

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Cars")
    public class CarDO implements java.io.Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -3769636546619492649L;
       private Long id;
    
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
       @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
       public Long getId() {
          return id;
       }
       public void setId(Long id) {
          this.id = id;
       }
   }
```

*Table Creation*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Colour] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Price] [BIGINT] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `nativeQuery=true` from your query

Comment: This is the how. The why is because Hibernate defaults to BigInteger or BigDecimal when a native query returns a number to ensure no data loss. If the query is in JPQL, then it knows to use the specific type from that returned column.